# When posting a photo, TypeError: 'unicode' does not have the buffer interface

Tags: python, unicode

I'm trying to use the `tumblpy` package to queue a photo. I recently changed from the Canopy python distro (on Windows, version 2.7.6 IIRC) to Anaconda (with Python 2.7.7), and this error never occurred.

When I run this:

```
import tumblpy
t = tumblpy.Tumblpy(hidden_key1, hidden_key2, hidden_key3, hidden_key4)
photo = open('C:/Users/David/Documents/Images_API/med_aerotransport.jpg', 'rb')
photo
```

output is:

```
<open file 'C:/Users/David/Documents/Images_API/med_aerotransport.jpg', mode 'rb' at 0x0000000006161270>
```

Now when I try to post the photo:

```
response = t.post('post',
                  blog_url='http://postersvintage.tumblr.com/', 
                  params={'type':'photo',
                          'state':'queue',
                          'caption': 'Vintage Med Aerotransport poster',
                          'tags':'vintage, poster',
                          'data': photo})
```

Here's the entire error trace, leading to `TypeError: 'unicode' does not have the buffer interface`:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-32-c560435c7a77> in <module>()
      5                           'caption': 'Vintage Med Aerotransport poster',
      6                           'tags':'vintage, poster',
----> 7                           'data': photo})

C:\Users\David\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\python_tumblpy-1.0.2-py2.7.egg\tumblpy\api.pyc in post(self, endpoint, blog_url, extra_endpoints, params)
    170     def post(self, endpoint, blog_url=None, extra_endpoints=None, params=None):
    171         return self.request(endpoint, method='POST', blog_url=blog_url,
--> 172                             extra_endpoints=extra_endpoints, params=params)
    173 
    174     def get_avatar_url(self, blog_url, size=64):

C:\Users\David\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\python_tumblpy-1.0.2-py2.7.egg\tumblpy\api.pyc in request(self, endpoint, method, blog_url, extra_endpoints, params)
    124                 if files:
    125                     kwargs['params'] = params
--> 126                 response = func(url, **kwargs)
    127         except requests.exceptions.RequestException:
    128             raise TumblpyError('An unknown error occurred.')

C:\Users\David\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\requests-1.2.2-py2.7.egg\requests\sessions.pyc in post(self, url, data, **kwargs)
    375         """
    376 
--> 377         return self.request('POST', url, data=data, **kwargs)
    378 
    379     def put(self, url, data=None, **kwargs):

C:\Users\David\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\requests-1.2.2-py2.7.egg\requests\sessions.pyc in request(self, method, url, params, data, headers, cookies, files, auth, timeout, allow_redirects, proxies, hooks, stream, verify, cert)
    322 
    323         # Prepare the Request.
--> 324         prep = req.prepare()
    325 
    326         # Send the request.

C:\Users\David\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\requests-1.2.2-py2.7.egg\requests\models.pyc in prepare(self)
    223         p.prepare_headers(self.headers)
    224         p.prepare_cookies(self.cookies)
--> 225         p.prepare_body(self.data, self.files)
    226         p.prepare_auth(self.auth, self.url)
    227         # Note that prepare_auth must be last to enable authentication schemes

C:\Users\David\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\requests-1.2.2-py2.7.egg\requests\models.pyc in prepare_body(self, data, files)
    383             # Multi-part file uploads.
    384             if files:
--> 385                 (body, content_type) = self._encode_files(files, data)
    386             else:
    387                 if data:

C:\Users\David\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\requests-1.2.2-py2.7.egg\requests\models.pyc in _encode_files(files, data)
    131             new_fields.append((k, new_v))
    132 
--> 133         body, content_type = encode_multipart_formdata(new_fields)
    134 
    135         return body, content_type

C:\Users\David\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\requests-1.2.2-py2.7.egg\requests\packages\urllib3\filepost.pyc in encode_multipart_formdata(fields, boundary)
     75                                'filename="%s"\r\n' % (fieldname, filename))
     76             body.write(b('Content-Type: %s\r\n\r\n' %
---> 77                        (content_type,)))
     78         else:
     79             data = value

TypeError: 'unicode' does not have the buffer interface
```

Comment: I strongly suspect your `requests` version is too old; upgrade it to the latest version.

Comment: You are quite correct, updating ``requests`` to 2.4.0 entirely solved the problem. How strange that Anaconda defaults to 1.2.2.

Comment: 1.2.2 is about 16 months old, not *that* ancient perhaps. `tumblpy` requires that version or newer, but I guess they haven't run in to this specific issue. Perhaps you need to supply them with a bug report?

Comment: Capital idea. I'm doing so now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue solved by updating `requests`, as suggested by Martijn Pieters.